# Find another way to prove the answer: circles with four numbers in them

Tags: pattern, sequence

[image: puzzle and answer explanation]

I know of an alternate solution to 3 where trying to find it would make an interesting puzzle. Can anyone do so?

It has to involve a sequence somehow.

Source: https://www.indiabix.com/puzzles/number-puzzles/93

Comment: Any alternative solution is speculative. You are basically asking us to guess what alternative solution you have come up with. As such, this question is not fit for this site.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you found an alternative way to *prove* the answer is 3, or that you can prove a different *answer*.